# Getting network on mainthread exception after App returns from resume on Parse initialization

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

So I am using parse framework in my Android app and everything works great except for one little thing. When I push the app into the background and resume it after while. I am getting

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1009)
        at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.close(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:205)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.close(DefaultClientConnection.java:161)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.closeConnection(AbstractConnPool.java:320)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.shutdown(AbstractConnPool.java:296)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.shutdown(ConnPoolByRoute.java:670)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.shutdown(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:256)
        at com.parse.ParseRequest.initialize(ParseRequest.java:104)
        at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:108)
```

I am not sure how to prevent that and it only happens when the application comes back after beeing a very long time in the background.

I heard from somewhere that, this behaviour only happens on KitKat but this is by no means a reassurance. I already thought about performing the initialization in a separate thread but I couldn't get it to work (I am new to this)

I initiliaze parse by performing this code in my Activity:

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx", "xxxxx"); 
  }
```

I hope someone who is using the parse framework has a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its becuase you are using `Networkservice` in your main thread and that is not allowed in the android so create a new thread and call a netwokservice from that. some thing like this.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {     
            // your logic for network service   
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not call this method from a new thread in your Activity. In fact, the [official Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/?com/parse/ParseObject.html) advises you not to call this method from an Activity at all. Rather, you should call `parse.initialize` from the `Application.onCreate()` method, instead of your Activity.onCreate() method. I didn't think this was a big deal to just call it from `Activity.onCreate()`, but apparently it is, especially in KitKat. This is fairly simple to implement, though. Create a new java class file that extends `android.app.Application`. The file should have the exact same name as your project (case sensitive). Something like:

```
package com.your_package.your_project_name;

import com.parse.Parse;

import android.app.Application;

public class your_project_name extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "your application id", "your client key");
        //if you need to, initialize ParseFacebookUtils, etc. here
    }
}
```

Comment: What about Analytics/PushService etc? Safe to put it all in there or shall that be called in the onCreate(Activity)? EDIT: Just checked their other samples, safe to call Push in Application too. Thanks man :)

Comment: Should be safe to put it in there. The order of initializations can be a factor for certain things. For instance, if you're going to use the local datastore, you need to call "Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);" before you call Parse.initialize. After calling Parse.initialize, you can call set up push (PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, PushActivity.class);) and ParseFaceBookUtils.initialize, ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened, etc. My pleasure! I've had a lot of luck with Parse, but it's a pain to get it all figured out!

Answer (score 1):

You could try just sticking that line in an AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Parse.initialize();
    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with AsyncTask. Write AsyncTask class in your main class that you want to do your operations. If you want, you can create the progress dialog in preexcecute of your async class and dismiss in onpostexecute of async class to show a loading indicator while your AsyncClass does parsing operation. Here is how you will do this:

```
  class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
     ProgressDialog pd;
     Context co;
     MyActivity ma;

     public MyAsync (MyActivity ma){
         this.ma= ma;
         this.co = ma;
         pd= new ProgressDialog(co);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         this.pd.show();

     super.onPreExecute();
     }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx", "xxxxx"); 
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // show results after parse and dismiss progress dialog pd.dismiss();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
```

in MyActivity call as :

```
MyActivity ma = this;
new MyAsync(ma).execute();
```